# dificuldade em fazer ForEach lambda em uma query

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho essa query

```
var qry = _productRepository.Table.GroupJoin(_categoriesRepository.Table,
            p => p.CategoryId,
            c => c.Id,
            (p, c) => new { Product = p, Categories = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
            .Where(hdg => hdg.Product.Hidden == false)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SelectMany(final => final.Categories,
            (final, c) => new CatalogItemResponse
            {
                ChildrenCategoryId = final.Product.ChildrenCategoryId,

                DolarRate = 0.0m,
                ResellerPriceUSD = 0.0m,
                ResellerPriceBRL = 0.0m,
                BasePriceBRL = 0.0m,
                BasePriceUSD = 0.0m,

                CategoryId = final.Product.CategoryId,
                CategoryName = (c != null ? c.Name : null),
                PictureId = final.Product.PictureId,
                Description = final.Product.Description,
                ShortDescription = final.Product.ShortDescription,
                Name = final.Product.Name,
                NameHtml = string.IsNullOrEmpty(final.Product.NameHtml) ? final.Product.Name : final.Product.NameHtml,
                PartNumber = final.Product.PartNumber,
                Hidden = final.Product.Hidden,
                Order = final.Product.Order,
                HaveMaximumPercentage = final.Product.HaveMaximumPercentage,
                MaximumPercentage = final.Product.MaximumPercentage,
                HaveMinimumPercentage = final.Product.HaveMinimumPercentage,
                MinimumPercentage = final.Product.MinimumPercentage,
                AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration = final.Product.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration,
                AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration = final.Product.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration,
                StandardMarkup = final.Product.StandardMarkup,
                DistributionCenterErpId = final.Product.DistributionCenterErpId,
                PictureFilename = final.Product.Picture.FileName

            }).ToList();
```

Antes dessa lambda eu tinha um GetAll() e depois fazia um foreach e pegava essa linha da forma que está

```
if (product.PictureId.HasValue)
    q.PictureFilename = product.Picture.FileName;
```

Bem, o que eu preciso é pegar esse mesmo valor, mas atribuindo dentro da qry.ForEach e não estou sabendo fazer. Comecei a tentar dessa forma

```
 qry.ForEach(prd => prd.PictureFilename = ??????)
```

Isso está correto, é dessa forma?

**EDIT1**

Fiz dessa forma, colocando a classe Picture no Left Join, mas o que eu atribuo no Select new? Dei um select new anônimo, o que faço? Qualquer valor que tento setar, dá erro na parte inferior

```
var qry = _productRepository.Table.GroupJoin(_categoriesRepository.Table,
            p => p.CategoryId,
            c => c.Id,
            (p, c) => new { Product = p, Categories = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })

            .GroupJoin(_pictureRepository.Table,
            prd => prd.Product.PictureId,
            pic => pic.Id,
            (prd, pic) => new { Product = prd.Product, Pictures = pic.DefaultIfEmpty()})
            .SelectMany(sel => sel.Pictures,
            (sel, pic) => new
            {

            })

            .Where(hdg => hdg.Product.Hidden == false)            
            .SelectMany(final => final.Categories,
            (final, c) => new CatalogItemResponse
            {
                ChildrenCategoryId = final.Product.ChildrenCategoryId,
                //atribuições.................
```

Incluir isso

```
GroupJoin(_pictureRepository.Table,
                prd => prd.Product.PictureId,
                pic => pic.Id,
                (prd, pic) => new { Product = prd.Product, Pictures = pic.DefaultIfEmpty()})
                .SelectMany(sel => sel.Pictures,
                (sel, pic) => new
                {

                })
```

Veja esse screenshot do erro em cima dessa linha: `.Where(hdg => hdg.Product.Hidden == false)` 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade a sintaxe correta seria do `ForEach()`:

```js
qry.ForEach(prd => {
    //DoSomething
});
```

Veja se atende seu problema:

```js
var qry = _productRepository.Table.GroupJoin(_categoriesRepository.Table,
          p => p.CategoryId,
          c => c.Id,
          (p, c) => new { Product = p, Categories = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
          .Where(hdg => hdg.Product.Hidden == false)
          .AsNoTracking()
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(PropertyDescriptor => {
            //DoSomething
          });

var listCatalogItems = qry
        .SelectMany(final => final.Categories,
        (final, c) => new CatalogItemResponse
        {
          ChildrenCategoryId = final.Product.ChildrenCategoryId,

          DolarRate = 0.0m,
          ResellerPriceUSD = 0.0m,
          ResellerPriceBRL = 0.0m,
          BasePriceBRL = 0.0m,
          BasePriceUSD = 0.0m,

          CategoryId = final.Product.CategoryId,
          CategoryName = (c != null ? c.Name : null),
          PictureId = final.Product.PictureId,
          Description = final.Product.Description,
          ShortDescription = final.Product.ShortDescription,
          Name = final.Product.Name,
          NameHtml = string.IsNullOrEmpty(final.Product.NameHtml) ? final.Product.Name : final.Product.NameHtml,
          PartNumber = final.Product.PartNumber,
          Hidden = final.Product.Hidden,
          Order = final.Product.Order,
          HaveMaximumPercentage = final.Product.HaveMaximumPercentage,
          MaximumPercentage = final.Product.MaximumPercentage,
          HaveMinimumPercentage = final.Product.HaveMinimumPercentage,
          MinimumPercentage = final.Product.MinimumPercentage,
          AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration = final.Product.AuthorizeMaximumPercentageAlteration,
          AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration = final.Product.AuthorizeMinimumPercentageAlteration,
          StandardMarkup = final.Product.StandardMarkup,
          DistributionCenterErpId = final.Product.DistributionCenterErpId,
          PictureFilename = final.Product.Picture.FileName

        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Victor, tentei fazer assim, mas o problema é que eu não consigo mais pegar Product no ForEach e não sei como adicionar. Em qry eu tenho apenas CatalogItemResponse

Comment: E se você fizer o ForEach() antes de mudar sua lista para CatalogItemResponse, atenderia?

Comment: E como eu faria isso? De que forma, veja que qry é a query principal, em momento eu pegaria essa informação?

Comment: Veja a ideia que eu alterei no tópico, eu criei uma lista só para armazenar a informação e fazer as alterações e depois eu crio minha lista de CatalogItemResponse a partir dos dados alterados

Comment: Dá erro: `var qry = _productRepository.Table.GroupJoin(_categoriesRepository.Table,
          p => p.CategoryId,
          c => c.Id,
          (p, c) => new { Product = p, Categories = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
          .Where(hdg => hdg.Product.Hidden == false)
          .AsNoTracking()
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(PropertyDescriptor => {
            //DoSomething
          });` Esse bloco explode esse erro: Não é possivel atribuir void a uma variável de tipo implícito

Comment: Por acaso está usando o PropertyDescriptor como uma variavel no foreach()? Se for for realmente vai dar uma exception, pois ali vc deve declarar uma variável correspondente ao item corrente do ForEach() e não uma classe como o PropertyDescriptor

Comment: .ForEach(nomeVariavel => { //DoSomething })

Comment: Cara, não estou conseguindo rodar seu código acima. Não está funcionando, dá o erro no comentário acima. Sabes o que pode estar causando isso?